# Convert list of tuples into numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How to convert this:

```
x = [(65535, 9976, 65535, 5690, 6.8501953124999995), (65535, 8779, 65312, 5045, 21.178124999999998)]
```

to numpy array?

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
np.asarray(x)
```